# Writing data to cells in Excel, C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

reading from Excel cells works perfect. But i have problems with writing new data to worksheet3 and cells[8,2].. How to fix this code?

I'm getting error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   File not available.

But i can read from this file using other button.

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Base.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(3);

// range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

//  Object[,] saRet;
//  saRet = (System.Object[,])range.get_Value(Missing.Value);

xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, 2] = "Salary";

xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
xlApp.Quit();

releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: you should post the errors you are receiving.

Comment: Any chance base.xls is currently open?

Comment: No, i closed all excel.exe, and I also changed "true" to "false", because ReadOnly was "true".

Comment: Make sure your process has read access to the file.

Comment: Be sure there are no other invisible "EXCEL.EXE" running in the background that could have the file open. Do you have administrative rights?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I set the content of the cell is like this:

```
 xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, 2].Value = "Salary";
```

I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: Is it possible if I implement this code with ASP.net sir?

Comment: @Bcktr Yes, I think so. This needs solution needs COM interop, so I guess it will not work with .NET Core

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a range to a string:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, 2] = "Salary";
```

Try something like:

```
xlRange = (Excel.Range) xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, 2];
xlRange.Value = "Salary";
```

Comment: You're probalby right with this , butFile is still not available. Maybe there's something wrong with xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open and writing data? Reading data is working correctly..

Comment: Using Interop.Excel version 15, I am able to set data using `Sheet.Cells[x,x] = "Data"`

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the excel file in readonly mode.

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Base.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

And you are setting editable to false. This is probably the reason why you cannot edit the file...

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Base.xls", 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line in your code:

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Base.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

The third parameter defines is your file shoul be opened as read-only. You set it to true, that meens you can not modify your file. I think that is why you have an error "file not available".

Answer (score -1):

Your code appears to be fine. The problem could be with the file.

Open file in Excel. Do you see any write protection message? Make sure that you are able to manually modify its content and can save the file. Give a try.

[image]